# Android Firebase RecyclerView get Item

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView that populates from Firebase(so it uses Firebase own Recycler adapter), I want to get information about the objects displayed the same way I do with my Listview, which is a lot simpler in this case: just adding addOnItemTouchListener on the listView will do it. But the recyclerView doesn't have this method, a similar one is addOnItemTouchListener and I can't understand how can I get item information from it, as the methods don't include an index or some sort of identificacion for the rows.

I've tried searching on the problem but I lack the understanding of this "new" method, or I can't formulate the approrpiate question for this.

```java
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Partida partida = (Partida) recyclerView.getChildItemId(motionEvent.getActionIndex());

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {

            }
        });
```

I expect to get the attributes of my class "Juego" but I don't know how to get it in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: Is there `LayoutManager` attached along with Firebase Recycler Adapter?

Comment: @VedprakashWagh  `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a View.OnClickListener in onBindViewHolder of your adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the View from RecyclerView through LayoutManager that you've used.

Check out the code below:

```
View v = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
```

With this you'll be able to get the View at position(but not the actual data object). You can extract the data from `TextView` or `EditText` if there's any using methods like

```
String name = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewId)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: And how do I access said position? I have an onclickitemlistener for my recyclerview but it doesn't give any parameter like that.

Comment: Do you have Viewholder in your firebase recycler adapter?

Comment: yes, I believe it's this: `public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
//...
`

Comment: If you have a viewholder, then you can do the click handling in viewholder itself.